# Input number in excel in Row1,And next time goes to next empty row

Tags: excel, vba

Basically what I want to do is input my number to A2 to D2. Next time to input my numbers go to A3 to D3. I made a macro to dialog box to ask my number. I Upload my excel through this link. [I assigned a star shape to my macro](https://www.filemail.com/d/yssqkewzbzbzxsz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below codes.

```
Sub Dialogbox1()
Dim myValue As Variant

    myValue = InputBox("Input Entry")
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Value = myValue

End Sub
```